# How to post data to web API with specified ID parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to post data to web API with specified ID for instance, "localhost:/companies/34/employees/"
So I need to give it an ID to specify which entity I'll post to.

Here I've tried this code but it doesn't work

```
[HttpPost("{bId:int}/employees/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostEmployee(int bId,[FromBody] Employee emp)
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _context.Companies.Where(i=>i.branchId==bId).Employees.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetEmployee", new { id = emp.employeeId }, emp);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean `it doesn't work` ? can you show me the error ?

Comment: `...it doesn't work...` - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Mostly the issue you are facing is related to the value binding in the API exposed `PostEmployee`, as per my guess Employee object `emp` is not filled, which is causing trouble, thus its a data binding issue, once you confirm, also provide details how you are calling API including value of Employee object in the body

Answer (score 1):

you can pass id parameter by using [FromRoute] in controller parameter

```
[HttpPost("{bId}/employees/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostEmployee([FromRoute] int bId,[FromBody] Employee emp)
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _context.Companies.Where(i=>i.branchId==bId).Employees.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetEmployee", new { id = emp.employeeId }, emp);
}
```